# Python: Return pre stored json file in response in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django

I want to write an API, which on a GET call , returns pre-stored simple json file. This file should be pre-stored in file system. How to do that?

register is app name. static is folder inside register. There I keep stations.json file. register/static/stations.json.

Content of this "stations.json" file should be returned in response.

settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'register/static/')
]
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.conf import settings
import json



class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    
    
def get_stations(request):
    with open(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '/stations.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from register.views import RegisterView
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='auth_register'),
    path('stations/', views.get_stations, name='get_stations'),
]
```

setup/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('register.urls')),
]
```

When I hit GET request from Postman: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stations/",

I get error: 500 Internal server error.

TypeError at /api/stations/

Error:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
    <title>TypeError
        at /api/stations/</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback

Comment: Did you try to open the file with the hardcoded path like so : `with open('register/static/stations.json', 'r') as f:` ?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM : It is a Big HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass safe=False in return JsonResponse(data)  as return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)